# two php dynamic variable syntax passed in javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, variables, syntax

I am trying to pass two variables in a **JavaScript** function that pop up a confirmation box before deleting a record from the database **MySQL**, but I think there is something wrong in the syntax.

Below is the code of the link that fires the confirmation box when it is clicked but it doesn't work and I am not sure if I am passing the parameters in a right way:

```
echo"<td><a href='javascript:promptbox(" . $myemail . "," . $appNo .")'>cancel</a></td>";
```

Can someone please let me know whether its a syntax error or is there any other problem?

Thanks

Comment: You have an XSS hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in Javascript needs to be enclosed by quotes.

```
echo"<td><a href='javascript:promptbox(\"" . $myemail . "\",\"" . $appNo ."\")'>cancel</a></td>";
```

Comment: If those two variables are coming from users, please consider using `htmlspecialchars` to avoid XSS attacks!

Comment: @SLaks He may have to use it twice but it will prevent it! of course, **NOT** allowing dangerous chars would be much better and safer!

Comment: @undone: No.  HTML-escaping text does not help when concatenating Javascript.